# Optimized way to handle constant map data

Tags: java

I have a map data already with me in string format for eg -

```
in = ch.ed, 
au = nsw.syd, 
us = ny.nj, 
ca = on.to,
```

Can someone please suggest which data structure i should use in java to put this data in.
"Enummap" or a "hashmap" or if any other suggestions ?
What are advantages if i use "enummap".
My  map will remain unchanged throughout the package.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main [difference](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/difference-between-enummap-and-hashmap-in-java-vs.html) between `EnumMap` and `HashMap` is that `EnumMap` is a specialized `Map` implementation exclusively for `Enum` as key.

So If your `keys` are the type `Enum`  go for a `EnumMap` otherwise Go for HashMap.

There are some advantages of having `ENUM` as a key,Because

> Key Of Map should be unmodifiable and Unique and this can be guranteed using Enum.

Prefer to read : [EnumMap or HashMap if lookup key is a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445274/enummap-or-hashmap-if-lookup-key-is-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sorted map then use Tree Map.

If requirement is to iterate on the entries in the same order as they were put,consider LinkedHashMap

Otherwise always prefer the HashMap if you dont care about any of the above criteria

EnumMap is a specialized Map implementation for use with enum type Keys.see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html.So if your keys are of Enum types go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for static `HashMap` which can be initialized and filled at the time of application start up. Other `classes` can only get the values from Map. You can wrap that `map` around a `bean` and only that bean will be accessible by all `classes`. What I am trying to tell you is, you should go for `singleton` design pattern.